# How to modify Content-Type in apache

Tags: apache

We are currently having Content-Type: text/html.

We want to modify this to text/javascript or text/css.

We have tried this using rewrite rule, mod_headers and also through mod_mime, but we are unable to modify it.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have certain text files in a directory say `styles` add a .htaccess file in the root directory and add the following content:

```
<Location /styles>
  ForceType text/css
</Location>
```

And use the similar concept for javascript as well

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this by changing the content type in application servers of content.

Comment: Please add more details to your answer.

Comment: Changing to what?